# Source Azure Service principal yaml

Tags: bash, azure, shell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I am writing a shell script to delete Virtual machines in Azure. As part of that, I need to access a YAML file (as shown below) that has azure service principal for different subscriptions. Now I am not sure how to load this YAML file in my script.

```
  123456-5897-1223357-7889:
    subscription_id: "123456789"
    client_id: "123456789"
    secret: "123456789"
    tenant: "1234567899"
    azure_cloud_environment: "AzureCloud"

  578945-5897-1223357-7889:
    subscription_id: "987456123"
    client_id: "987456123"
    secret: "987456123"
    tenant: "987456123"
    azure_cloud_environment: "AzureCloud"
```

is there a way to source this file as we do in GCP or is there a way to load the file from YAML file

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="/tmp/project1.json"
gcloud config set project project1
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible to do that, the only auth option you can do (with a file) is replacing `.azure/azureProfile.json` (cant recall right now for sure, it might be another file under `.azure` folder) under users profile, but its format is completely different (not sure where you got these files).

Comment: there is no command for that, it just reuses the login data stored on disk if its there